# ArrayAdapter обработка вложенного массива

Tags: android, массивы, kotlin, android-spinner

имеется кастомный class содержащий в себе Array с данными другого Class'а

```
   private Test class {
    var Test_name: String? = null
    var test_array: Array<_Test>
  }
```

имеются два Spinner'а

```
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<Test>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Test)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)


    spinner.adapter = adapter
    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long) {
            val con: Test
            if (spinner.selectedItem != null)
            {
                con = spinner.selectedItem as Test
                myTextView.text = String.format("Test: " + con.Test_name + "\t id: " + con.Test_array)//просто тест
                TwoSpinnerContent()
            }
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>) {

        }
    }

}
fun TwoSpinnerContent(){
    val adapterSpTwo = ArrayAdapter<Test>(applicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, /*ТУТ*/)
    adapterSpTwo.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    spinnerTwo.adapter = adapterSpTwo
}
```

Как собственно во втором spinner'е обратится и высвисти массив _Test содержащийся в spinner.selectedItem  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте в метод `TwoSpinnerContent` этот массив `Array<_Test>`.

```
TwoSpinnerContent(con.test_array)
```

Тогда сигнатура метода будет

```
fun TwoSpinnerContent(tests: Array<_Test>)
```

Соответственно, `tests` и будет тем недостающим параметром для создания `ArrayAdapter<_Test>`.

Comment: Да вы все правильно поняли(для лучшего понимания я изменил код в вопросе)

Comment: Обновил ответ с соответствии с кодом вопроса.